# Error "Could not resolve mscorlib for target framework '

Tags: linq-to-entities, mvp, .net-framework-version

I am trying to add an entity of my database, MS 2012 web express return the error

"Could not resolve mscorlib for target framework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'. This can happen if the target framework is not installed or if the framework moniker is incorrectly formatted."

And had search some online help, where I cant solve it by locating "TargetFrameworkProfile" from

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/542789/could-not-resolve-mscorlib-for-target-framework-netframework-version-v4-0-this-can-happen-if-the-target-framework-is-not-installed-or-if-the-framework-moniker-is-incorrectly-formatted

And had no clue how to change the path size solution from the reply

"At last Keeping Path to my Solution below 256 character Solved The problem ."

Can anyone help on step by step how to solve the entity problem so I can continous my web building.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell from your question if this is actually the problem you're having, but;

```
"At last Keeping Path to my Solution below 256 character Solved The problem."
```

basically means that you need to keep your solution in a directory that is not buried too far down in the file system. In other words, try copying your solution directory from wherever it is to a directory name at the root (for example `C:\Dev`) and open it from there, and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help, had just tested, looks like not the solution or problem at there :(

Answer (score 0):

Changing the path to `c:\project` solve the problem.

Thank you.